# Export data to csv file set values to not right cells

Tags: c#, csv, datagridview, export-to-excel

I use next code to export data from datagridView into xls file.

```
private void ToCsV(DataGridView dGv, string filename)
{
    var stOutput = "";
    // Export titles:
    var sHeaders = "";

    for (var j = 0; j < dGv.Columns.Count; j++)
        sHeaders = sHeaders + Convert.ToString(dGv.Columns[j].HeaderText) + "\t";

    stOutput += sHeaders + "\r\n";
    // Export data.
    for (var i = 0; i < dGv.RowCount - 1; i++)
    {
        var stLine = "";
        for (var j = 0; j < dGv.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
        stLine = stLine + Convert.ToString(dGv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value) + "\t";

        stOutput += stLine + "\r\n";
    }

    var utf16 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1254);
    byte[] output = utf16.GetBytes(stOutput);
    var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
    var bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
    bw.Write(output, 0, output.Length); //write the encoded file
    bw.Flush();
    bw.Close();
    fs.Close();
}
```

As result i get "bad" formated file :

[image: xls-file]

I don't know why file content is like this (some text aren't in right columns). Any suggestion? Thanks.

---

Is it possible because some text for cell has "newLine" `\n` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose all your values (or at least the ones being a potential issue) with double quotes. Instead of `123\n` put `"123\n"` in your csv file.

This issue is most of the time encountered when using decimal separator in csv files, like explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/568429/excel-csv-import-treating-quoted-strings-of-numbers-as-numeric-values-not-strin). Your `\n` case looks a lot alike.

Comment: And one More... what you can suggest if text for cell already contains double quotes?

Comment: Did you even try to search? Double quote will act as an escaped quote, [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12473480/how-should-i-escape-commas-and-speech-marks-in-csv-files-so-they-work-in-excel).