# Including commas when writing to csv file in java, with different string each time

Tags: java, csv

I'm writing a program where I need to write data to csv. However the string what I'm writing to csv has some commas. So when I'm writing to it I'm getting values in different fields, which I don't want
Eg: my string will come like : 165328,1234582,21346
I'm getting output as each value in one field, but I want the string as it is in one field

```
        while((s=lnr.readLine())!=null)
        {
                     str=s.split(" ");
                     br.write(str[7]);
        }
```

Please add the required thing to get the desired output.
Eg : the string I'm writing will look like this 165328,123482,123414...

Comment: Duplicate. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12473480/how-should-i-escape-commas-and-speech-marks-in-csv-files-so-they-work-in-excel and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617935/is-there-a-way-to-include-commas-in-csv-columns-without-breaking-the-formatting and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file

Comment: for this one, I'm having diff string each time

Answer (score 4):

Write the string which contains comma in double quotes and then write it into the csv file with File Writer or any writer you wish .

```
 value="\"" +value + "\"";
 fos.append(value);
```

Comment: tried this alreday, its appending without commas, I'm getting output like..1523278123 without commas(concatenated two numbers, without comma)