# ignore commas within string in JSON when exporting to csv

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, export-to-csv, filesaver.js

I'm exporting json files to csv using [Filesaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) and [json-export-excel.js](https://github.com/dtagdev1/json-export-excel). The comma separator is causing the columns to shift when it sees a comma in the string.

### [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zNM8LU3lnktMkTI79BdD?p=preview) Demo

How can i ignore commas found within string?

```
<button ng-json-export-excel data="data" report-fields="{name: 'Name', quote: 'Quote'}" filename ="'famousQuote'" separator="," class="purple_btn btn">Export to Excel</button>
```

JS File:

```
$scope.data = [
  {
    name: "Jane Austen",
    quote: "It isn\'t what we say or think that defines us, but what we do.",
  },
  {
    name: "Stephen King",
    quote: "Quiet people have the loudest minds.",
  },
]
```

Current CSV output (Not Desired): (Note: `|` marks the columns in csv file)

```
Name          Quote                                        
Jane Austen |  It isn't what we say or think that defines us|   but what we do.|
Stephen King|  Quiet people have the loudest minds.         |                  |
```

Desired CSV output:

```
Name          Quote                                        
Jane Austen |  It isn't what we say or think that defines us, but what we do.|
Stephen King|  Quiet people have the loudest minds.                          |
```

Comment: did you tried to escape the separator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Excel, you need to wrap values in quotation marks. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12473480/how-should-i-escape-commas-and-speech-marks-in-csv-files-so-they-work-in-excel).

In `json-export-excel.js` you'll see that the `_objectToString` method wraps the output in quotes but because the `fieldValue` variable isn't an object this is never called for this example.

```
function _objectToString(object) {
  var output = '';
  angular.forEach(object, function(value, key) {
    output += key + ':' + value + ' ';
  });

  return '"' + output + '"';
}

var fieldValue = data !== null ? data : ' ';

if fieldValue !== undefined && angular.isObject(fieldValue)) {
  fieldValue = _objectToString(fieldValue);
}
```

If you add an `else statement` to this to wrap the value in quotes, the CSV opens in Excel as desired.

```
} else if (typeof fieldValue === "string") {
  fieldValue = '"' + fieldValue + '"';
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3fVDaZ6QZqKWD5vLWxqs?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked!! I tried console.logging "output" inside _objectToString function and the values still got logged (without the double quotes) even tho the function is not called?

Comment: @Jason I just tried to log `object` inside `_objectToString` and I'm not seeing anything. Have you changed the data?

Comment: i think I was logging the `output` from `output += key + ':' + value + ' '`... so i'm actually not logging `object`